# How can I add text (to enable searching and copy&paste) to a scanned PDF document?

Tags: pdf

I have Microsoft Word document. Someone has printed that document, signed it (yes. With a pen. Very nostalgic.) and then scanned it. Obviously this process turned the document into images making it hard to search them or copy&paste text from them.

I tried an OCR-Tool and after running that tool the document is visually identical to the scan and I can search and copy&paste text. However checking this for OCR-errors is cumbersome and I don't even know how to correct any errors that I found. Also it does seem completely unnecessary because I still have the original Word-document.

How can I embed or otherwise combine the scanned document and the original Word-document in such a way that you see the scan, but the text selection and searching behaves like the original Word document?

A solution based on OpenSource software (pdftk, qpdf,...) that works offline on Linux is preferred.

Comment: The question was closed as off-topic. However the [linked suggestions](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5372/) clearly state the format of _"I have <problem-x> that I don't know how to solve. I've already tried X, Y, Z, but those programs don't work because this or that. How do I do this?"_ as acceptable. I think this question follows this pattern, so I am at odds why this is closed.

Comment: I agree this question should be reopened, it appears it will be. The primary reason it was closed, I think, is that it uses phrases commonly used to ask that a product be recommended for a solution. I can see why you included that information, and agree it is relevant info to your question, but that last sentence could be phrased differently to avoid those close votes. It's a bit of a hang up on this site, to be honest. Lots of people want to be told "X software will solve your problem" rather than being led through a sometimes complex set of steps, and so lots of questions get closed for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result using `pdftk` and the `multistamp` command.

First export the M$-Word document as PDF file as `document.pdf` and the signed file as `document_signed.pdf`. Then combine the two documents as follows:

```bash
pdftk document.pdf multistamp document_signed.pdf output document_signed_searchable.pdf
```

This creates a `document_signed_searchable.pdf` with exactly the features you want.

Here is the relevant excerpt from the manual:

```
background <background PDF filename | - | PROMPT>
    Applies a PDF watermark to the background of a single input PDF.  Pass the background PDF's filename after background like so:
  
    pdftk in.pdf background back.pdf output out.pdf
  
    Pdftk uses only the first page from the background PDF and applies it to every page of the input PDF.  This page is scaled and rotated as needed to fit the input page.  You can use - to pass a background PDF into pdftk via stdin.
  
    If the input PDF does not have a transparent background (such as a PDF created from page scans) then the resulting background won't be visible -- use the stamp operation instead.
  
multibackground <background PDF filename | - | PROMPT>
    Same as the background operation, but applies each page of the background PDF to the corresponding page of the input PDF.  If the input PDF has more pages than the stamp PDF, then the final stamp page is repeated across these remaining pages in the input PDF.
  
stamp <stamp PDF filename | - | PROMPT>
    This behaves just like the background operation except it overlays the stamp PDF page on top of the input PDF document's pages.  This works best if the stamp PDF page has a transparent background.

multistamp <stamp PDF filename | - | PROMPT>
    Same as the stamp operation, but applies each page of the background PDF to the corresponding page of the input PDF.  If the input PDF has more pages than the stamp PDF, then the final stamp page is repeated across these remaining pages in the input PDF.
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the whole point of the document is it is a signed copy of the source (otherwise no point adding a signature).

Then you need to return the signature to where it should have been signed and that means add it back to the source DocX as if signed in Word, where it can be archived as a true PDF copy. For Linux you will clearly need to use Open or LibreOffice. Otherwise you would need to add the scan into the Media Folder of the DocX and a highly elaborate addition to the Document XML.

[image]
[image]

This way there can be no doubt it is the source searchable signed document without any fear of corruption  or degredation by OCR.

[image]